# How to add list property values

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code. How can I add values to this properties?

```
APIKarhoBookingProperties objbooking = new APIKarhoBookingProperties();
objbooking.currency = "USD";
objbooking.price_components = ??? //how to add values this section

class APIKarhoBookingProperties
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public List<PriceComponent> price_components { get; set; }
}

public class PriceComponent
{
    public string component_name { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Mhm, it's basic syntax.Even in vs it's pretty intuitive. :-) And no I won't google it for you, neither give you a fish)

Comment: should have googled it before, posting here :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read some c# basics, [List](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

```
price_components.Add(new PriceComponent(){ 
            component_name = "name", 
            value = 2, 
            description = "dgfdgf", 
            currency = "USD" });
```

Comment: Yes you're right, It's pity that Stack not allowing to put link-answers from LetMeGoogleThatForYou.

Answer (score 1):

```
APIKarhoBookingProperties objbooking = new APIKarhoBookingProperties();
  objbooking.currency = "USD";
  objbooking.price_components = new List<PriceComponent>() {
new PriceComponent{component_name = "abc", value = 1.0, ...},
new PriceComponent{component_name = "xyz", value = 2.9, ...},
new PriceComponent{component_name = "def", value = 1120, ...},
...
}; 
  class APIKarhoBookingProperties
  {
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public List<PriceComponent> price_components { get; set; }
  }
  public class PriceComponent
  {
        public string component_name { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
  }
```